# php and mysql syntax issues using update statements

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to figure out the syntax problem in my query
the block of code goes like this:

```
$updatequery = "update patient_dim set dentist_id = $dentist_id where".
                "patient_id = $patient_id";
$queryResult = mysql_query($updatequery,$con);

if(!$queryResul){
      trigger_error("insert error" . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
```

then the error goes like this:
Notice: inssert errorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"1" where patient_id = 4'

i suspect incorrect syntax in the $updatequery statement

for further information value of the $patient_id = 1 while the value of the $dentist_id = 4, i have tried all of your approaches still the same error. anyway thanks your helping

Comment: give a space after `where` condition

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and learn about prepared statements.

Comment: To troubleshoot an error like this normally you would output your query to a string and try to execute it manually. Doing this would highlight, as @AbhikChakraborty noted, you are missing a space.

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs `space` after where

```
$updatequery = "update patient_dim set dentist_id = $dentist_id where patient_id = $patient_id";
```

Comment: still does not work, same error with the syntax, all values of the variable is correct

Comment: Can you update your question with echoed value of query

Answer (score 1):

```
$updatequery = "update patient_dim set dentist_id = $dentist_id where".
            " patient_id = $patient_id";
```

you forgot to add space after WHERE clause

Comment: I would go as far to say you might as well remove the concatenation and just have one, one line, query string ("update patient_dim set dentist_id = $dentist_id where patient_id = $patient_id")

Answer (score 0):

After WHERE Clause there must be a blank space before the condition.
Use as follows.

```
<?php
    $updatequery = "update patient_dim set dentist_id = ".$dentist_id ." where patient_id = ".$patient_id;
    $queryResult = mysql_query($updatequery);
    if(!$queryResult){
         die("insert error" . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: i tred your approach and still the same error, and all variables has the correct value

Comment: echo $updatequery and try to execute the query in SQL Editor(PhpMyadmin),It will help you to catch the error.Can you please change the variables in if statement from $queryResul to $queryResult (It is a typo Mistake).I am editing the query,Please try again.

Comment: i already figure out the typo , there's a mistyped / in the other parts of the code. anyway thank you helping out